# The Movie Database popular people api with ionic 3

Tags: api, ionic3, themoviedb-api

I'm trying to build a ionic 3 app using the movie database api.

The popular people page in my app views the list using the site's api as it would be. The problem i'm facing is when to click on the actor/actress name, the people-detail page should view everything the site has on them. But the api uses the actor/actress ID in the api. I used the person's ID as a variable and pushed it to the people-detail page (as shown below), and I retrieved it using navparams, but nothing seems to work. The browser's console shows the json contents, but I can't retrieve it in the people-detail.html.

I'm trying to find a solution to retrieve the json and view it in the people-detail.html

I need your help, thanks in advance...

note: I hid the apiKey as it's a private key.

Here is what I did to clarify:-

people.html:-

```
<ion-content padding>
  <ion-list *ngFor="let people of peoples">
    <ion-item (click)="openPeopleDetailPage(people.id)">
      <ion-avatar item-start>
        <img src="{{'https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w600_and_h900_bestv2'+people.profile_path}}">
      </ion-avatar>
      <h2>{{people.name}}</h2>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

people.ts:-

```
export class PeoplePage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, private peoplesprovider: PeoplespProvider) {

    //popular peoples
    this.peoplesprovider.getPeople().subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data.results);
      this.peoples = data.results;
    });

  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad PeoplePage');
  }

  openPeopleDetailPage(people: any){
   this.navCtrl.push(PeopleDetailPage, {people:people})
  }

}
```

peopleProvider.ts:-

```
@Injectable()
export class PeoplespProvider {

 people_url: string= "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/person/popular?<api_key>";

  constructor(public http: HttpClient) {
    console.log('Hello PeoplespProvider Provider');
  }

  getPeople(){
    return this.http.get(this.people_url)
  }

  getPeopleDetail(peopleId: number){
    return this.http.get('https://api.themoviedb.org/3/person/${peopleId}? 
    <api_key>')
  }

}
```

people-detail.ts:-

```
 export class PeopleDetailPage {

 people: any;
 detail: any;

 constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, 
 private peoplesprovider: PeoplespProvider) {

 this.people = this.navParams.get('people');
 }

 ionViewDidLoad() {
 console.log('ionViewDidLoad PeopleDetailPage');

 const peopleId = this.people.id;
 this.peoplesprovider.getPeopleDetail(peopleId).subscribe(data => {
  console.log(data);
  this.people = data;
 });
 }

 }
```

people-detail.html:-

```
<ion-content padding>
 <div>
 <div text-center>
  <img class="people-img" src=" 
 {{'https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w600_and_h900_bestv2'+people?.profile_path}}">
</div>
<div>
  <h1 text-center>{{people?.name}}</h1>
</div>

<div>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-segment [(ngModel)]="controls" color="secondary">
      <ion-segment-button value="info">Info</ion-segment-button>
      <ion-segment-button value="movies">Movies</ion-segment-button>
      <ion-segment-button value="tv-shows">TV Shows</ion-segment-button>
    </ion-segment>
  </ion-toolbar>
</div>

<div [ngSwitch]="controls">

  <div *ngSwitchCase="'info'">
    <ion-grid>
      <ion-row>
        <p>Born on <b>14/02/1986</b></p>
      </ion-row>
      <ion-row>
        <p text-wrap>From <b></b></p>
      </ion-row>
      <ion-row>
        <p>Also known as <b>Alex Daddario</b></p>
      </ion-row>
    </ion-grid>
    <p text-wrap>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem.</p>
  </div>

  <div *ngSwitchCase="'movies'">
    <ion-list>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-thumbnail item-start>
          <img src="assets/imgs/1.jpg">
        </ion-thumbnail>
        <p class="movie-year">2018</p>
        <h2 text-wrap>The Big Bang Theory is here</h2>
        <p class="role-name">Constance Blackwood</p>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-thumbnail item-start>
          <img src="assets/imgs/1.jpg">
        </ion-thumbnail>
        <p class="movie-year">2018</p>
        <h2>Cher</h2>
        <p class="role-name">Constance Blackwood</p>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-thumbnail item-start>
          <img src="assets/imgs/1.jpg">
        </ion-thumbnail>
        <p class="movie-year">2018</p>
        <h2>Cher</h2>
        <p class="role-name">Constance Blackwood</p>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
  </div>

  <div *ngSwitchCase="'tv-shows'">
    <ion-list>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-thumbnail item-start>
          <img src="assets/imgs/1.jpg">
        </ion-thumbnail>
        <p class="movie-year">2018</p>
        <h2 text-wrap>The Big Bang Theory is here</h2>
        <p class="role-name">Constance Blackwood</p>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-thumbnail item-start>
          <img src="assets/imgs/1.jpg">
        </ion-thumbnail>
        <p class="movie-year">2018</p>
        <h2>Cher</h2>
        <p class="role-name">Constance Blackwood</p>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-thumbnail item-start>
          <img src="assets/imgs/1.jpg">
        </ion-thumbnail>
        <p class="movie-year">2018</p>
        <h2>Cher</h2>
        <p class="role-name">Constance Blackwood</p>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: where is the people-detail.html code? also any error logs in the console?

Answer (score 0):

In your people.html it seems that when you're opening a person's details youre pushing the person's ID but in your people-detail.ts you assigned this id to a people variable. When you're fetching the details later, you're using
Const peopleid = this.people.id
This should not be the case. Try using
Const peopleid = this.people.

Comment: but i get the json request the way i want it from people-detail.ts .. the problem is in people-detail.html.. how can i bind it to view it??

Answer (score 0):

In your `people.html` you are saying **people.id**;

```
<ion-item (click)="openPeopleDetailPage(people.id)">
```

But in `people-detail.ts` you are saying

```
this.people = this.navParams.get('people');
```

... and then

```
const peopleId = this.people.id;
```

This code is trying to access **people.id.id**, but that doesn't exist (I guess?).

**SOLUTION**

Try using this instead:

```
const peopleId = this.people;
```

This should give you the right ID. And btw, I see that you do `this.people = data;` in the end of your code. I would recommend you creating a different object for this data, instead of overwriting your peopleId-object. For instance, in top of you file:

```
peopleData: any;
```

And then, you just say:

```
this.peopleData = data;
```

Remember to replace all the `people.`-interpolations in `people-detail.html` to `peopleData.`